# $array expondo resultado seguinte?

Tags: php

Em meu código fiz ao final dele para que a array fizesse uma sequencia logica e sequencial da minha busca mas a mesma não está funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);

//chama o arquivo de conexão com o banco

include("connect_db.php");

//consulta mysqli

$query = mysql_query("SELECT numero, orig, dest, eqpt, rota FROM voos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

//aqui ele gera looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))

{

echo $array['numero'];
?><br />
Origem:  <?php
echo $array['orig'];
?><br />
Destino: <?php
echo $array['dest'];
?><br />
Aeronave: 
<?php
echo $array['eqpt'];
?><br />
Rota: <?php
echo $array['rota'];
?><br /><?php

}
    ?> 
    $orig = $array->dest;
    }
    $dest = $orig;
    } 
    <?php

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//consulta mysqli

$query = mysql_query("SELECT numero, orig, dest, eqpt, rota FROM voos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Faltou colocar a conexão na query... 
mysql_query("SELECT...", $con)

E essa parte realmente está fora, sem utilidade:

```
$orig = $array->dest;
}
$dest = $orig;
}
```

Funcionando como quer:
(podem ter outras formas, fiz assim para entender o passo a passo)

```
//aqui ele gera looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
while($i = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $array[] = $i;
}

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($array);
$r = 0;

foreach ($array as $i) {

    //print_r($i);

    echo $array[$r]['numero'];
    ?><br />
    Origem:  <?php
    if ($r == 0) { echo $array[$r]['orig']; } else {
        echo $array[$r-1]['dest'];
    }
    ?><br />
    Destino: <?php
    echo $array[$r]['dest'];
    ?><br />
    Aeronave: 
    <?php
    echo $array[$r]['eqpt'];
    ?><br />
    Rota: <?php
    echo $array[$r]['rota'];
    ?><br /><?php

    ++$r;
}
```

Para evitar origem e destino iguais:
foreach ($array as $i) {

```
foreach ($array as $i) {

//print_r($i);
if ($array[$r-1]['dest'] == $array[$r]['dest']) continue;

echo $array[$r]['numero'];
```

Comment: $orig = $array->dest;
}
$dest = $orig;
} 

Mas essa parte é a mais importante, estou conseguindo buscar os resultados mas queria que eles viessem nessa ordem que eu fiz ou tentei fazer.

Comment: Mas isso aí não tem sentido algum...
O que você quer ver como resultado na sua tela ?

Comment: Estou listando uns voos, pelo menos é minha ideia, gostaria que fosse assim:

Numero Do Voo:
Origem: XXXX
Destino: XXXX

E a segunda listagem seria 
Numero Do Voo
Origem : ESS ORIGEM ser  ultima do Destino do resultado acima.

Comment: Eita !
Não é assim que faz então cara...
Você está buscando do banco, com RAND ainda, é diferente disso !

Comment: Respondi a baixo.

Comment: Desculpe, não consigo ver tudo isso agora...
Mas basicamente seria da seguinte forma:

1 - Gera todo um array em uma variável, ao invés de imprimi-lo enquanto consulta
2 - Com foreach, faz a impressão, mas na origem você puxa do array anterior do 2o resultado para frente

Obs: terá que fazer um if porque o 1o resultado, não irá puxar a origem do array anterior

Comment: Agradeço muito Raoni mas não tenho conhecimento para isso ainda, sigo estudando ms está complicado.

Comment: Postei funcionando como quer... mas podem ter outras formas...
Da forma que fiz seguindo um exemplo mais simples de se entender...

Comment: Raoni eu coloquei ele para testar mas mesmo assim não esta saindo em uma sequencia logica, seria algo em meu query ? ou SELECT ?

Comment: Você pode ver aqui como esta saindo o resultado: http://www.latamvirtual.net/core/cria_voo.php

Comment: Ué está correto !
Você não queria que o destino do em cima fosse a origem do debaixo ?

Comment: Caso for isso, e estiver ok, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido na resposta, assim ajuda o próximo !

Comment: Raoni estou tentando só uma coisa, o segundo resultado esta trazendo a origem e destino igual, como posso arrumar isso por favor ?

Comment: Você copiou o código e colou ?
Se sim, não tem como dar problema !
Só se coincidir do destino anterior for igual ao destino do próximo !
Aí você teria que ter outro if, para pular o registro, já que não teria o voo.

Comment: Inclusive, você tem registro vazio no seu banco... exclui ele...

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada aqui e inserir mais registros para ver o que acontece.

Comment: Raoni desculpas novamente vir aqui, estava olhando o codigo e chega alguns momentos ele copia os resultados por exemplo:
TAM3002
Origem: SBSP
Destino: SBSP
Aeronave: A320
Rota: DCT SANBO UZ64 NEGUS DCT
TAM3000
Origem: SBSP
Destino: SBSP
Aeronave: A319/
Rota: DCT SANBO UZ64 NEGUS DCT

Sendo que no Banco de dados esses voos são registros diferentes.

Comment: Pelo código que te passei não tem como ! Eu testei ! Ele puxa o que está em cada regosto, mas substitui a origem a partir da 2a exibição !

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte do código esta fora da tag php e também há } a mais no código.

```
$orig = $array->dest;
}
$dest = $orig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

E se eu listasse dessa forma ? Problema que dessa forma não consegui adequar, tudo.

```
//aqui ele gera looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query)
foreach($array as $indice => $item)
{
    if(isset($array[$indice + 1])){
        echo $array[$indice]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice]['rota'];
        echo "<br>";
        //Se for o item 2 primeiro inverta a parte de baixo com a de cima
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['numero'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['orig'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['dest'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['eqpt'];
        echo $array[$indice + 1]['rota'];
```